# How to find volume Volume serial number or Harddisk number from drive letter

Tags: python, windows

I have a function written in windows using python 2.7 which produces removable device letter. Now i want to take backup of boot sector of this device. I have done this on linux easily with following command

```
dd if=/dev/sdb1 of=~/backup.bs count=1
```

Now i want to do the same under windows using windows version of dd. However for that i need to find out the hadrdisk and the actual command would be

```
dd if=\\?\Device\Harddisk0\Partition0 of=backup.bs skip=41287113 count=1
```

or

```
dd if=\\.\Volume{c18588c0-02e9-11d8-853f-00902758442b} of=c:\temp\backup.bs count=1
```

Now how do i find out `Volume{c18588c0-02e9-11d8-853f-00902758442b}` or `Harddisk0\Partition0` from the known label like `D: or E: or F:` etc.
Using windows7 and python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. For the benefit of all posting it here.

```
import wmi
c = wmi.WMI ()
drive_letter = "D:"
for physical_disk in c.Win32_DiskDrive ():
  for partition in physical_disk.associators ("Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition"):
    for logical_disk in partition.associators ("Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition"):
      if logical_disk.Caption == drive_letter:
        print physical_disk.Caption, partition.Caption, logical_disk.Caption
```